# To Show selected Icon as Active, when icon or icon list is clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

[image]

[image]

I'm using Leaflet for non-geographic image (like floor plan).

Feature to implement:

1. Load the dynamic(markers) icons created on the non geographic image based on x,y coordinates.

   - was able to do this using unproject.
2. On hover of any marker show the product/item details as the popup/tool tip.

   - was able to do this with option - title - add the object data while creating markers.
3. On clicking any item in the list (towards left in the image attached) or corresponding marker in the map container the icon
   should be shown as active by color change on any simple style.

I'm seeking the solution for the 2 and 3.

Below is the code I tried.

```
planPos = [
{
  x: 1500,
  y: 500,
  item: 'Sensors',
  Model: 'ABC',
  Make: 'Bosh',
  Elevation: '2.3 meters',
  Criticality: 'High',
  Accessibility: 'Concrete',
  LocationType: 'Kitchen',
  Zone: 'Annexure',
  ZoneType: 'Building',
  Restriction: 'Securenced',
  ZoneNotes: 'The is big sentence at the room level and building',
  PositionDetails: 'One of the position details near the room and details',
  InstallationNotes: 'One of the big resource for the building',
  Status: 'Active'
},
{
  x: 125,
  y: 45
},
{
  x: this.w * 0.5,
  y: this.h * 0.5
}];


mapInit() {
// create the slippy map
this.map = L.map('image-map', {
  attributionControl: false,
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 4,
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 1,
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
});


this.myFeatureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(this.map).on("click", this.groupClick);
// calculate the edges of the image, in coordinate space
this.southWest = this.map.unproject([0, this.h], this.map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
this.northEast = this.map.unproject([this.w, 0], this.map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
this.bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(this.southWest, this.northEast);

// add the image overlay, 
// so that it covers the entire map
L.imageOverlay(this.url, this.bounds).addTo(this.map);

// tell leaflet that the map is exactly as big as the image
this.map.setMaxBounds(this.bounds);

this.planPos.forEach(p => {
  L.marker(this.map.unproject([p.x, p.y], this.ACTUAL_SIZE_ZOOM), {
    draggable: true,
    title: `item: ${p.item}
    \n Model: ${p.Model}
    \n Make: ${p.Make}
    \n Elevation: ${p.Elevation}
    \n Criticality: ${p.Criticality}
    \n Accessibility: ${p.Accessibility}
    \n LocationType:  ${p.LocationType}
    \n Zone: ${p.Zone}
    \n ZoneType: ${p.ZoneType}
    \n Restriction: ${p.Restriction}
    \n ZoneNotes: ${p.ZoneNotes}
    \n PositionDetails: ${p.PositionDetails}
    \n InstallationNotes: ${p.InstallationNotes}
    \n Status: ${p.Status}`,
    name: p.Make
  });
 });
}
```

Comment: since you're using a library to generate the HTML of your markers, you may have to add some jQuery. add a `(click)="onClickItem(itemId)"` in the HTML of your left list. And in the `onClickItem` method, select the marker from its id, or name, or whatever, and add a "selected" CSS class. Have you tried something like this ? Not sure it's the most elegant solution since I've never used Leaflet, but I think it should work.

Comment: Yes have tried that, but was unsuccessful as we will not be able to directly add the css class to the marker. I tried with clusterGroup for layering markes then add css class which dint work, based on the some of the answers and suggestion in stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you create a small demo to reproduce this?

Comment: Does the API allow you to Change the Marker Icon ?
Did this with Google Maps some time ago. Not Sure about leaflet